# SQLAlchemy and DDD

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, domain-driven-design

I am implementing an application using a DDD approach. I want to separate domain model into a separate package, declare a Repository and the implementation will use SQLAlchemy as ORM in a separate package.

From the domain standpoint, a User looks like:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.id = autogenerate_id()
        self.name = name
```

But for SQLAlchemy, it should be implemented as:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

My question is: is there any way of minimizing the amount of work that is needed to define the SQLAlchemy model such that:

1. I don't have to write mapping code from domain-SQLAlchemy and viceversa
2. I can "guarantee" that I didn't forget to include any attribute from domain in the SQLAlchemy counterpart (when making changes to the domain model).

Comment: Does this not help you at all? "A Table object can be instructed to load information about itself from the corresponding database schema object already existing within the database" http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html

Comment: @GreenMagic I wonder if that's such a good idea, since your domain model and database model can differ significantly, for a variety of reasons ranging from performance to technical impracticalities (e.g. no obvious default way to map inheritance) to legacy data.

Comment: The [Cosmic Python](https://www.cosmicpython.com/) book explores implementing DDD with SQLAlchemy in some depth.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to have two implementations of aggregate DTO without mapping sqlalchemy table to python data struct. In this case, I would recommend you create UserDTO interface that will be implemented by SQLAlchemy Model and by you plain domain implementation (for tests?).

```py
class User:
    id: int
    name: Text

class PlainUser(User):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.id = autogenerate_id()
        self.name = name

class DBUser(db.Model, User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

About mapping DTO to DB and strategies on how to accomplish it. Also about I write more in this post [Persistency of DDD aggregate](https://lzukowski.github.io/2020-04-17/ddd_persistency/)

Hope it will help you with other question that you will have down the road with DDD (for example separate migrations in modular monolith architecture).